# Debugging service workers of push notifications for firefox mobile?

Tags: firefox, browser, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I am using the 'Web push notificatoins API' to send notifications from my server to my website.

Long story short - the notifications are received and shown by all major browsers except firefox android (ios untested). I suspect the service worker file to be the culprit but have no idea how to debug see/log its errors / messages.

The service_worker.js :

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        console.log('back) ;
        return;
    }
    const sendNotification = body => {
        const title = "BTC changed - coinvalue.me";
        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body,
        });
    };

    if (event.data) {
        const message = event.data.text();
        event.waitUntil(sendNotification(message));
    }
});
```

Question: How to debug the results of this file? Firefox WebIDE doesn't show any console.log()

Edit : Firefox version 54.0.11 on android 4.2.1

Comment: You can follow this guide (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE) which will allow you to see Firefox for Android logs on your desktop machine.

Comment: already using remote debugging,it doesn't show service_worker log :(